# Internal Server Error due to set_time_limit in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to run the following PHP script on my shared hosting to make it run forever:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(TRUE);
set_time_limit(0);

include_once("function.php");

while (TRUE) {
  if (file_exists("stop_test.txt")) {
    echo "Break File Exists!";
      break;
  }
  // Do something, but even with commenting this section, I face internal server error too!
  sleep(30);
}

exit();
?>
```

But I face "Internal Server Error" after about one minute. I contacted my hosting provider and asked them about the problem and they have told me that there is no problem on server side and these kind of cron-like scripts are allowed on their shared hosting and suggested me to review my code.

I couldn't figure out why this script results in Internal server error, what is the problem with my script?

Comment: [time limit docs](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) is PHP safe mode on? Secondly webservers are not designed to handle connections that live for a long time. Did you ever think about changing the implementation?

Comment: Did you check the server logs. If you're getting an error, it should be recorded in the logs. Without that information about why it crashed, you're not going to get very far. I would also echo @Xorifelse's comment: Making a PHP script run forever over a web server is a **really** bad idea. It will have a noticeable impact on the performance of the server as a whole. Much better to have it a short-lived program that runs periodically as a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, however directly setting the ini using `ini_set()` seems to have corrected the issue:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

However, as suggested in the comments, it's really best practice to set some sane limit (30 seconds or so).